# OOP - factory pattern - handling specific subclasses

Tags: oop, factory

I have a factory, that is responsible for constructing objects of interface HTMLTagElement. The interface represents HTML element and has methods to get tag name and manipulate element attributes.

However, I have lots of sub classes and many of them have other public methods, that are specific just for the certain class. For instance Panel class:

```
class Panel implements HTMLTagElement
{
    /**
     * @param string $sTitle
     */
    public function setPanelTitle($sTitle)
    {

    }

    /**
     * @param string $sBody
     */
    public function setPanelBody($sBody)
    {

    }

    /**
     * @param string $sIconPath
     */
    public function setPanelIcon($sIconPath)
    {

    }
}
```

The factory is still returning the reference just for HTMLTagElement, so in order to use the Panel class methods, I need to downcast it to Panel. (I know that PHP is dynamic language and there is no downcasting, but this is more like OOP question, not PHP question)

So, am I doing that right? Wouldn't be better to create a new factory class, that would return the reference to concrete Panel class? Then I would however need a factory class for every subclass of HTMLTagElement, that adds some new methods, so I am not sure, if it's good either.

Comment: It really goes to the question of why are you using a factory to begin with. What specifically are you trying to abstract?

Comment: I don't want the application code to worry about creating instances of these classes. I want the factory to do all the job and handle dependencies. When I use just "new Panel()", I lose possibility to inject there some Panel subclass. But when I have a factory method, I could invoke it like this - HTMLTagElementFactory::createElement('panel', $attributes) and based on attributes or some other factory intern options, I can return whatever I want and have creating instances in one place.

Comment: So to answer your question, I am trying to abstract everything reusable. I have many subclasses, that I am directly referencing in my code. However all instances are created by this one factory, so in my code, I need to just "believe" the factory, that the returned HTMLTagElement is really the desired one subclass that I need. I am sure, that this is not the right way. What I can think of is creating factory for every subclass, that I want to abstract, and call it like this HTMLPanelFactory::createPanel($attributes) : Panel

Comment: Is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145546/Factory-Pattern-using-Generics) related to what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the link and yes, it's related, but it's specific for .NET and other strongly typed languages. In PHP, I can't define class to accept a "type(K,T)" parameter like "public class FactoryPattern <K,T> ". All I can do is to send some parameters to the factory and hope, that based on that parameters, the factory returns the right instance.